# Does the $slice function in MongoDB Meteor work?

Tags: mongodb, meteor

Does the `$slice` function work in Meteor MongoDB?

Here is some query sample:

```
 Posts.find({"permalink":"udrskijwddhigfwhecxn"},{"comments":{"$slice":10}});
```

I tried querying in the mini MongoDB and directly through publish using parameters, but it always return the complete nested data.

```
{
    _id:Object(1231o2j3lkqj),
    body:"this is body",
    author:"machine",
    permalink:"udrskijwddhigfwhecxn"
    title:"this is title",
    tags: ["dog","cat","tree"]
    comments: [{
       body:"comment body",
       author:"lara",
       email:"email@ab.com"
    },
    ...]
    date:ISODate("2013-03-16T02:50:27.881Z")
}
```

Comment: It looks like it may only be implemented as a modifier for `$push` and not as a projection operator as you are using it. At least that's what experimentation and the changelog lead me to believe.

Comment: did you tried `Posts.find({"permalink":"udrskijwddhigfwhecxn"},{fields:{"comments":{"$slice":10}}})`? The projection in meteor is specified by `fields`.

Comment: From what I can see in the [docs](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/fieldspecifiers), `fields` allows only 1/0 for exclusion/inclusion. Unless the docs are wrong/outdated?

Comment: Nevermind, I believe @Vishwas is correct in this case. Meteor docs refer to [this](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/project-fields-from-query-results/#projection-for-array-fields), which means that nesting it in `fields` might work.

Comment: @Vishwas this worked in my case using projection `fields`.

Comment: @Vishwas Yes, it works on the server-side. But in this case, all other fields of the document are returned as well. What do I do if I only want to return the comment field, which I would normally do with comments:1 ?

Comment: @waldgeist you can just specify unwanted fields with `0`  and wanted fields as `1` like `Posts.find({"permalink":"udrskijwddhigfwhecxn"},{fields:{"comments":{"$slice":1‌​0}},"author":0,"title":0}

Comment: @Vishwas: Yes, I know, but I would need the 1 for exact the same field as the $slide, i.e. { comments: 1, comments: { $slice: 10 } }, which is not possible as JSON does not support that you state the same key twice.

Comment: @waldgeist You can specify all other fields to 0 which will give only `comments` at the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can split the following. by using The **projection** in Meteor and it is specified by `fields`.

```
Posts.find({"permalink":"udrskijwddhigfwhecxn"},
{
fields:{"comments":{"$slice":1‌​0}}
})
```

Comment: throws me: Uncaught Error: Projection values should be one of 1, 0, true, or false. weird.

Comment: I get this error: `Uncaught Error: Minimongo doesn't support operators in projections yet.`

Comment: @StephenM347 yes. i think you should use this query in the server side